# Error with encode / decode in html generated for outlook

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I have 2 functions, the first prepares the html and writes to a .txt file. The second function opens this file and manages an email through Outlook.

In the body of the message, the content of this html will be placed with the correct formatting. Everything goes perfectly, the .txt comes with the html without any errors, but when Outlook is opening it, it is closed and the Error / Exception is generated below:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 529: ordinal not in range(128)

I know that this `\xe7` is `ç`, but I can not solve it, I've already tried to define it by `.decode("utf-8")` and `.encode("utf-8")`, in the variable `email_html_leitura`, but the error of codec persists. Follow the code of the 2 functions to see if I did something wrong:

Function 1:

```
import sys
import codecs
import os.path

def gerar_html_do_email(self):
    texto_solic = u'Solicitação Grupo '
    with codecs.open('html.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf8') as email_html:
        try:
            for k, v in self.dicionario.iteritems():
                email_html.write('<h1>'+k+'</h1>'+'\n')
                for v1 in v:
                    if (v1 in u'Consulte o documento de orientação.') or (v1 in u'Confira o documento de orientação.'):
                        for x, z in self.tit_nome_pdf.iteritems():
                            if x in k:
                                email_html.write('<a href='+'%s/%s'%(self.hiperlink,z+'>')+'Mais detalhes'+'</a>'+'\n')
                    else:
                        email_html.write('<p>'+v1+'</p>'+'\n')
                email_html.write('<p><i>'+texto_solic+'</i></p>'+'\n')
            email_html.close()
        except Exception as erro:
            self.log.write('gerar_html_para_o_email: \n%s\n'%erro)
```

Function 2:

```
def gerar_email(self):
    import win32com.client as com
    try:
        outlook       = com.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
        mail          = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To       = u"Lista Liberação de Versões Sistema"
        mail.CC       = u"Lista GCO"
        mail.Subject  = u"Atualização Semanal Sistema Acrool"
        with codecs.open('html.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf8') as email_html_leitura:
            mail.HTMLBody = """
                            <html>
                                <head></head>
                                <body>
                                    <style type=text/css>
                                        h1{
                                            text-align: center;
                                            font-family: "Arial";
                                            font-size: 1.1em;
                                            font-weight: bold;
                                        }
                                        p{
                                            text-align: justify;
                                            font-family: "Arial";
                                            font-size: 1.1em;
                                        }
                                        a{
                                            font-family: "Arial";
                                            font-size: 1.1em;
                                        }
                                    </style>
                                    %s
                                </body>
                            </html>
                            """%(email_html_leitura.read().decode("utf-8"))
        email_html_leitura.close()
        mail.BodyFormat = 2
        mail.Display(True)
    except Exception as erro:
        self.log.write('gerar_email: \n%s\n'%erro)
```

Comment: What if you use `"""%(email_html_leitura.read())` omitting the `.decode("utf-8")` there?

Comment: @JosefZ I had this suggestion on the stack in Portuguese, I remember to take the test and even though it did not work, maybe I did it wrong, I'm going to test tonight and I'll come back to see if it will work, thank you very much for the feedback and help. My english is from google translate, sorry.

Comment: I got the solution, I placed just below `import sys` the code:`reload (sys)` `sys.setdefaultencoding ('utf8')` and then it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help **JosefZ**.